# Filling an array with items from another array based on available space

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

How do I limit the "load space" (2nd part of the 2D array) of each truck to 1000? The do-while loop I have in the loadTrucks function does not work as intended. I've tried summing the array and limiting it utilizing a do-while, a while, and if/else statements in various combinations and to no avail. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int* initializePackages(int &numPackages);
void printArray(int* arr, int size);
void shufflePackages(int* packages, int size);
int** createTrucks(int &numTrucks);
void printTrucks(int** arr, int size);
void loadTrucks(int** trucks, int* packages, int numTrucks, int numPackages);

int main()
{
    int numPackages; //receives the passed in values from initializePackages.
    int numTrucks;  //receives the passed in values from createTrucks.

    srand(time(0)); //Seed the random function with the time clock.

    int* iPackages = initializePackages(numPackages);
    cout << "\nSorted Packages: \n";
    printArray(iPackages, numPackages);

    shufflePackages(iPackages, numPackages);
    cout << "\n\nShuffled Packages: \n";
    printArray(iPackages, numPackages);

    int** iTrucks = createTrucks(numTrucks);
    cout << "\n\nInitial Trucks: \n";
    printTrucks(iTrucks, numTrucks);

    cout << "\nLoaded Trucks: \n";
    loadTrucks(iTrucks, iPackages, numTrucks, numPackages);
    printTrucks(iTrucks, numTrucks);

}

int* initializePackages(int &numPackages)
{

    int* packages = 0; //returning the pointer from initializePackages.
    numPackages = 0;  //to pass the number of packages to main.

    cout << "Enter the number of packages to be loaded (between 60 and 500):  " << endl;
    while(numPackages < 60 || numPackages > 500){
        cin >> numPackages; //takes in the number of packages to be assigned.
    }

    packages = new int[numPackages]; //dynamically allocates an array of packages of based on the value of numPackages.

    for(int i=0; i < numPackages; i++){   //initializes the array with sequential values specified by numPackages.
        *(packages + i) = i +1;
    }

    return packages;
}

void printArray(int* arr, int size)
{
    for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++){
        cout << arr[count] << ((count + 1) % 20 ? " " : "\n"); //Accesses the array and prints out 20 elements per line.
    }
}

void shufflePackages(int* packages, int size)
{
    int j;      //additional variable to utilize as a swap variable.
    int temp;  //place holder variable.

    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){  //for loop to iterate through the shuffle sequence.
        j = rand() % size;           //selects random spot in the array to begin shuffling
        temp = packages[i];         //assigns a place holder variable to the initial value
        packages[i] = packages[j]; //empty packages[i] element is now assigned the value from the packages[j] element
        packages[j]=temp;         //packages[j] element is now assigned the initial value originally assigned to the place holder variable
    }
}

int** createTrucks(int &numTrucks)
{
        numTrucks = 0;


        cout << "\nEnter the number of trucks to be loaded (between 3 and 25):  "  << endl;
        while(numTrucks < 3 || numTrucks > 25){    //specifies the parameters for the number of trucks
                cin >> numTrucks;
        }

        int** trucks = new int* [numTrucks];    //dynamically allocates an array based on number of trucks.

        for(int i = 0; i < numTrucks; i++){   //accesses the truck array and assigns a number to each truck.
            trucks[i] = new int[20];         //dynamically allocates an array of 20 elements

            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){   //initializes the truck's available load space with zeros.
                trucks[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    return trucks;
}

void printTrucks(int** arr, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){   //loop to print out the trucks and number. "Truck #: "
        cout << "Truck " << i + 1 << ": ";

        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){ //loop prints out the available load space of the truck's trailer.
            cout << " " << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n"; //Starts a new line of truck and load space to be printed.
    }
}

void loadTrucks(int** trucks, int* packages, int numTrucks, int numPackages)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int temp;


    for(int i = 0; i < numTrucks; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < numPackages; k++){
                do{
                    temp = packages[k];
                    packages[k] = trucks[i][j];
                    trucks[i][j] = temp;
                    sum += trucks[i][j];
                }while(sum < 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numTrucks; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < numPackages; k++){
                if(trucks[i][j] + packages[k] < 1000)
                {
                    trucks[i][j] += packages[k];//adds the package quantity to the truck
                    sum += trucks[i][j];
                }
                else break; //gets to the next truck, because the quantity is already filled
            }
        }
    }
```

If what you want to achieve is what you say, then you need to do this. Check if you have room in the truck and add the current package to the truck. If the truck is full (1000+ quantity or 20 packages) you simply get to the next truck. `Break` exists the current loop and gets to the next truck.

Comment: Within my loadTrucks function or Main? Or like a quadruple nested for loop?

Comment: What does your `do-while` in `loadTrucks` intend to do?

Comment: it is supposed to limit each row to the sum of integers of each "package" (individual elements of [j] of trucks[i][j]) to within 1000 for the entire load.

Comment: maximum 20 packages can be loaded on
each truck. In addition, total size loaded on each truck cannot exceed 1000. For example, if a
truck is loaded with packages of sizes 100, 500, 300, 50, 30, 20, no more packages can be loaded
because total size loaded on this truck is already 1000 even though it only has 6 packages.
Get one packages at a time from the packages array, and load it to a truck with the most space
(size-wise). Load packages until there is no more truck to load or until there is no more
packages.

Comment: that is the goal of this function

Comment: @Bastard24, check my answer. Fixed for what you actually needed. If it helps, please check it and if it is ok, mark my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It iterated through the entire loop and display the last number in the in the packages in every element, but it is a step in a direction toward the correct logic.

Comment: You need maybe a double for and a `int countTotal = 0` and check at each step if you have any more space in the truck or if it should go to the other. Keep it up, it seems quite close to (or exactly) what you want to achieve, but maybe I did not fully understand you.

Comment: how do I increment a package to be loaded. I've tried various kinds of logical operators and am drawing a blank here.